# find command to remove files says that some files don't exist

Tags: command-line, files, find, xargs

I have an OSX Mountain Lion Laptop connected to and Ubuntu 11.10 system and tried to copy one `.csv` file from the OSX machine to the Ubuntu machine. I stopped the file transfer as I realised it created several empty files in the target folder.

I now have a few hundred files sitting there which I cant delete using:

```
sudo find . -name "*.csv" | xargs /bin/rm
```

It is saying file does not exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Don't use `xargs` without `-0`.**

<sub>(Yes, there are other safe ways of using `xargs`, but if you care about them, read them up elsewhere. If you don't care to memorize a lot of options and scenarios, just don't use `xargs`, there's usually a better way anyway.)</sub>

The problem with `xargs` is that its input must be quoted in a peculiar way that no other tool produces. In particular, it can't cope with spaces in file names. You don't say what the error are (for future reference, **copy-paste error messages**), but chances are that one of the matching file names contains a space, and xargs choked on it.

`xargs -0` copes with any strange character you may have in a file name. Pass `-print0` to `find` to make it print the names in the right format:

```
find . -name "*.csv" -print 0 | xargs -0 rm
```

Note that `sudo find …` only runs the `find` command as root, not the `rm` command. If you want to run `rm` as root, use

```
find . -name "*.csv" -print0 | sudo xargs -0 rm
```

Under Ubuntu (and also under OSX), you can use `find`'s built-in `-delete` option to delete matching files.

```
find . -name "*.csv" -delete
```

If you know that the files you want to delete are empty, better make the `find` command only look for empty files, so that you don't accidentally delete other files.

```
find . -name "*.csv" -type f -empty -delete
```

Comment: Unfortunately nothing but deleting the whole Desktop folder recursively did the job - thank you very much for your input though.